# Como puedo obtener un valor especifico de un archivo txt

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo txt super largo con 5 columnas que se repiten 3 veces, asi que son 15 columnas, consta de

```
Nombre,ion,LongOnd,da,abundancia
```

asi tres veces las mismas columnas, lo que quiero es obtener la abundancia de un cierto ion, con cierta longitud de onda, lo he estado intentando pero no veo resultados favorables.

les pongo un pedacito del txt y mi codigo.

```
FI R       83.0000m   34.960    1.1262      Fe 2      1.32055m   33.626    0.0522      N  2      
5754.61A   33.290    0.0241
TI R       1800.00m   33.092    0.0153      Fe 2      1.24854m   32.645    0.0054      N  2      
915.612A   31.997    0.0012
NI Ra      2.85000m   36.291   24.1132      Fe 2      7637.54A   33.077    0.0147      N  2      
2139.01A   32.920    0.0103
NI Rb      3.00000m   35.765    7.1930      Fe 2      4889.62A   32.774    0.0073      N  2      
1084.58A   31.927    0.0010
MI Ra      15.0000m   35.728    6.5980      Fe 2      4492.63A   32.191    0.0019      N  2      
915.962A   31.993    0.0012
MI Rb      22.5000m   35.835    8.4433      Fe 2      4457.94A   32.596    0.0049      N  2      
2142.78A   33.310    0.0252
```

y mi codigo

```
with open('Emergente_lines.txt') as temp_f:
datafile = temp_f.readlines()
for line in datafile:
    if 'N  2' in line:
        print(line)
        for item in line:
            del_letters = re.sub('[A-Za-z]', '', item)
            float_value = float(del_letters)
            if (float_value >= 5700) and (float_value <=5800):
                print(item)
```

Comment: Buen día, no se si es un ejercicio de tarea o un proyecto, pero ¿Tienes permitido utilizar otras librerías? Podrías hacerlo fácilmente con `pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con está función puedes leer el archivo y obtener su contenido como una lista de iones. Cada ion se representa con una lista de cinco campos.

```
def extraer_datos(archivo):
    iones = []
    with open(archivo, "r") as datos:
        for linea in datos:
            columnas = linea.split()
            for i in range(0, len(columnas), 5):
                iones.append(columnas[i:i+5])
    return iones
```

Cada línea del archivo de datos es separada por los espacios, obteniendo una lista de strings, los que son tomados de cinco en cinco y agregados a la salida, produciendo una lista como está:

```
[['FI', 'R', '83.0000m', '34.960', '1.1262'], 
 ['Fe', '2', '1.32055m', '33.626', '0.0522'], 
 ['N', '2', '5754.61A', '33.290', '0.0241'],
 ...]
```

La manera más sencilla de encontrar la información es con un `for` que recorra la lista y compruebe los campos específicos.

*ion.txt*

```
FI R       83.0000m   34.960    1.1262      Fe 2      1.32055m   33.626    0.0522      N  2      5754.61A   33.29
TI R       1800.00m   33.092    0.0153      Fe 2      1.24854m   32.645    0.0054      N  2      915.612A   31.99
NI Ra      2.85000m   36.291   24.1132      Fe 2      7637.54A   33.077    0.0147      N  2      2139.01A   32.92
NI Rb      3.00000m   35.765    7.1930      Fe 2      4889.62A   32.774    0.0073      N  2      1084.58A   31.92
MI Ra      15.0000m   35.728    6.5980      Fe 2      4492.63A   32.191    0.0019      N  2      915.962A   31.99
MI Rb      22.5000m   35.835    8.4433      Fe 2      4457.94A   32.596    0.0049      N  2      2142.78A   33.31
```

En este ejemplo, queremos los iones "N 2" cuya abundancia esté entre 0.0100 y 0.0200:

```
for ion in extraer_datos("ion.txt"):
    if ion[0] == 'N' and ion[1] == '2':
        abundancia = float(ion[4])
        if 0.0100 <= abundancia <= 0.0200:
            print(ion)
```

produciendo:

```
['N', '2', '2139.01A', '32.920', '0.0103']
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

**Nota:** La explicación es larga pero creo que te serviría mucho, el código en sí es corto.

**Edición:** Se me olvidó mencionar que el método read_csv  también acepta archivos txt, modifiqué el ejemplo

Si es posible utilizar `pandas` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

Cree un archivo (sample.txt) Con las filas de tus datos (El separador podría ser otro caracter, yo utilicé comas):

```
Nombre,ion,LongOnd,da,abundancia,Nombre,ion,LongOnd,da,abundancia,Nombre,ion,LongOnd,da,abundancia
FI,R,83.0000m,34.960,1.1262,Fe,2,1.32055m,33.626,0.0522,N,2,5754.61A,33.290,0.0241
TI,R,1800.00m,33.092,0.0153,Fe,2,1.24854m,32.645,0.0054,N,2,915.612A,31.997, 0.0012
NI,Ra,2.85000m,36.291,24.1132,Fe,2,7637.54A,33.077,0.0147,N,2,2139.01A,32.920,0.0103
NI,Rb,3.00000m,35.765,7.1930,Fe,2,4889.62A,32.774,0.0073,N,2,1084.58A,31.927,0.0010
MI,Ra,15.0000m,35.728,6.5980,Fe,2,4492.63A,32.191,0.0019,N,2,915.962A,31.993,0.0012
MI,Rb,22.5000m,35.835,8.4433,Fe,2,4457.94A,32.596,0.0049,N,2,2142.78A,33.310,0.0252
```

Al tener columnas duplicadas, lo que hace `read_csv` es agregarle un sufijo numérico a los nombres de las columnas repetidas, obteniendo las siguientes columnas:

```
['Nombre', 'ion', 'LongOnd', 'da', 'abundancia', 'Nombre.1', 'ion.1',
       'LongOnd.1', 'da.1', 'abundancia.1', 'Nombre.2', 'ion.2', 'LongOnd.2',
       'da.2', 'abundancia.2']
```

Podemos compactar el `dataframe` para que tengamos 18 filas y 5 columnas en lugar de 6 filas y 15 columnas al separar los datos en 3 grupos, cada grupo tendría las siguientes columnas

```
#Grupo 1
['Nombre', 'ion', 'LongOnd', 'da', 'abundancia']

#Grupo 2
['Nombre.1', 'ion.1', 'LongOnd.1', 'da.1', 'abundancia.1']

#Grupo 3
['Nombre.2', 'ion.2', 'LongOnd.2', 'da.2', 'abundancia.2']
```

Para poder crear los grupos utilizamos el método [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
df.iloc[:, :5]    #Esto crearía el primer grupo
df.iloc[:, 5:10]  #Esto crearía el segundo grupo
df.iloc[:, 10:]   #Esto crearía el tercer grupo
```

Para que podamos concatenar los grupos en un `dataframe` con 5 columnas es necesario que las columnas tengan los mismos nombres, para eso generamos un diccionario para el grupo 2 y uno para el grupo 3

```
g2 = {x: y for x, y in zip(df.iloc[:, 5:10].columns, df.iloc[:, :5].columns)}
```

Esto crearía el siguiente diccionario para el grupo 2:

```
{'Nombre.1': 'Nombre',
 'ion.1': 'ion',
 'LongOnd.1': 'LongOnd',
 'da.1': 'da',
 'abundancia.1': 'abundancia'}
```

Y por último utilizamos el método [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) para concatenar los grupos en un `dataframe`

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

#Obtener el dataframe, las columnas con nombres repetidos tendran un número de sufijo, por ejemplo Nombre.1, Nombre.2, etc...
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt')

#Creamos un diccionario con los nombres de las columnas 5-9 mapeados a los nombres de las columnas 0-4, por ejemplo {'Nombre.1': 'Nombre'}
g2 = {x: y for x, y in zip(df.iloc[:, 5:10].columns, df.iloc[:, :5].columns)}
#Creamos un diccionario con los nombres de las columnas 10-14 mapeados a los nombres de las columnas 0-4, por ejemplo {'Nombre.2': 'Nombre'}
g3 = {x: y for x, y in zip(df.iloc[:, 10:].columns, df.iloc[:, :5].columns)}

#Cada grupo de datos tiene 5 columnas, creamos 3 grupos utilizando iloc (Columnas 0-4, Columnas 5-10, Columnas 11-14)
#Renombramos las columnas de los grupos 2 y 3 para que tengan los nombres ['Nombre','ion','LongOnd','da','abundancia']
#Concatenamos los tres grupos de datos ignorando los índices para que a cada fila se le asigne un índice único
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :5], df.iloc[:, 5:10].rename(columns=g2), df.iloc[:, 10:].rename(columns=g3)], ignore_index=True)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    Nombre  ion LongOnd     da      abundancia
0   FI      R   83.0000m    34.960  1.1262
1   TI      R   1800.00m    33.092  0.0153
2   NI      Ra  2.85000m    36.291  24.1132
3   NI      Rb  3.00000m    35.765  7.1930
4   MI      Ra  15.0000m    35.728  6.5980
5   MI      Rb  22.5000m    35.835  8.4433
6   Fe      2   1.32055m    33.626  0.0522
7   Fe      2   1.24854m    32.645  0.0054
8   Fe      2   7637.54A    33.077  0.0147
9   Fe      2   4889.62A    32.774  0.0073
10  Fe      2   4492.63A    32.191  0.0019
11  Fe      2   4457.94A    32.596  0.0049
12  N       2   5754.61A    33.290  0.0241
13  N       2   915.612A    31.997  0.0012
14  N       2   2139.01A    32.920  0.0103
15  N       2   1084.58A    31.927  0.0010
16  N       2   915.962A    31.993  0.0012
17  N       2   2142.78A    33.310  0.0252
```

Para filtrar es muy fácil, únicamente tenemos que poner la comparación que deseamos hacer, por ejemplo, para filtrar todas las filas donde la columna "Nombre" sea igual a "N" hacemos lo siguiente:

```
print(df[df['Nombre'] == 'N'])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    Nombre  ion LongOnd     da      abundancia
12  N       2   5754.61A    33.290  0.0241
13  N       2   915.612A    31.997  0.0012
14  N       2   2139.01A    32.920  0.0103
15  N       2   1084.58A    31.927  0.0010
16  N       2   915.962A    31.993  0.0012
17  N       2   2142.78A    33.310  0.0252
```

Y si deseamos pasar más condiciones para filtrar filas las podemos agregar con `&` para hacer `and` y con `|` para hacer `or`. Por ejemplo:

```
df[((df['Nombre'] == 'N') & (df['abundancia'] > 0.01))]
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    Nombre  ion LongOnd     da  abundancia
12  N       2   5754.61A    33.29   0.0241
14  N       2   2139.01A    32.92   0.0103
17  N       2   2142.78A    33.31   0.0252
```

Si estás trabajando con muchos datos te recomendaría (Si es permitido en tu tarea/proyecto) utilizar `pandas` eso te facilitaría mucho buscar datos y hacer cualquier tipo de operaciones, por ejemplo digamos que quieres contar el número de elementos con el mismo nombre, podrías hacer algo así:

```
df.groupby(['Nombre']).size()
```

Y esto devuelve:

```
Nombre
FI    1
Fe    6
MI    2
N     6
NI    2
TI    1
dtype: int64
```

Entre otras muchas cosas que tal vez necesites hacer más adelante